# How do I display detrended data from a linear regression?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm just having a look through Hadley's very excellent book about his ggplot2 R package.

He has some code to remove a linear trend in the diamonds dataset, like so:

```
d <- subset(diamonds, carat < 2.5 & rbinom(nrow(diamonds), 1, 0.2) == 1)
d$lcarat <- log10(d$carat)
d$lprice <- log10(d$price)

detrend <- lm(lprice ~ lcarat, data = d)
d$lprice2 <- resid(detrend)

qplot(lcarat, lprice, data = d)
qplot(lcarat, lprice2, data = d)
```

Produces these graphs

Unadjusted...

[image]

Detrended...

[image]

I'd like to see what the actual values of lprice would be without the effect of lcarat. Plotting residuals vs lcarat shows the right shape, but the points are shifted toward y = 0 (look at the range of the y-axis units).

To get what I want, does it make sense to simply plot residuals + mean(lprice)? i.e. shift the previous graph up by mean(lprice).

```
qplot(lcarat, lprice2 + mean(lprice), data = d)
```

[image]

**Does it make sense to do this? Is there a name for what I'm trying to do?**

Comment: I think it's reasonable - I do it fairly frequently. Don't know of a name for it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This strikes me as a little odd and, in particular, (highly) **prone to misinterpretation**. How would you appropriately label your axes of the last plot to make it easier to interpret?

Comment: A side note -- if you plot a log-log graph, it is better to use [log axes](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_trans.html). Otherwise you suggest a linear relation between price and weight, which is in fact exponential.

Comment: @cardinal, what sort of misinterpretation do you mean? As for y-axis labels, the 3rd graph to me is "log(price) detrended" while the 2nd graph is simply "residuals".

Comment: @mbq, yes, fair point.

Comment: @TMOD, let's say, on your last plot, there is a point corresponding to $(-0.4, 3.3)$. Using just the plot, how would one interpret the meaning of that point? (The question is a bit rhetorical, with the point being to think about the information that the plot is, and is not, conveying.)

Comment: @cardinal, say I was looking for the most affordable diamonds regardless of size (number of carats). i.e. trying to find the best deal for cut and clarity. You're right that the last plot doesn't help much, but it's just confirming that the data is detrended for carats. I'd then do `d$lprice_detrended_carat <- mean(d$lprice) + resid(detrend)` and start looking at that. Maybe this doesn't make the most sense with logs, but the data I'm _actually_ applying this to is not log transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, it is terribly confusing, especially while you can do much simpler thing -- calculate `price/carat` to get a price of one carat, which would be way easier to interpret.

Comment: Note that `lprice` and `lcarat` are *log transformed*.

Comment: (The downvote is *not* mine.)

Comment: @cardinal Good point -- I mindlessly copied the variable names. However with log-log axes this makes even less sense ;-)

Comment: if you take the difference, then you get log(price/carat)